# Why does the method return a string when return type is Task<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have a question about asynchronous programming in C#. I want to know why a function that has a return type of Task has to return a string.
So even through I returned a string, it gets wrapped into a Task again - why is that?

Problem is that I have to explain this stuff to students. What is the reasoning behind wrapping the retourned string in a Task object even though I have just awaited the result on function return? I thought that the await statement blocks the continuation of the method until the result has arrived - that means on function call (await GetWeatherAsync()) there would be nothing to await since the result is already there...

Here is my sample code:

```
    static async void Download()
    {
        //I have just awaited the result in the function call. Why do I have to do this again at this point?
        Console.WriteLine(await GetWeatherAsync());
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetWeatherAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> t = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:59534/WeatherService.svc/rest?weekDay=Monday");
        HttpResponseMessage serverResponse = await t;

        return await serverResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Without the await at the end everything would make sense to me atleast - since i'd return a real task that might still have work to do...

Comment: In short: the `Task` returns a `string`. The method returns the `Task`.

Comment: Ah yea... let me rename it

Comment: What makes you think `GetWeatherAsync()` isn't returning a `Task<string>`? Try calling it without the `async` operator and you will get a `Task<string>` object.

Comment: read more about it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you mark a method as `async Task<string>` you are telling the consumer of it that the method promises to return you a `string` in the future.

I think you're getting hung up on the `await` keyword.  The `await` keyword allows you to pause execution of your method until the awaited task completes, treating it (to the consumer) as a synchronous method.

You can have an async method as simple as:

```
static async Task<string> SayHi()
{
    return "hi";
}
```

which you can consume using:

```
await SayHi() //returns a string
```

or

```
SayHi() //returns a Task<string>
```

along with all the benefits of `await`, it also unwraps your `Task` for you upon completion, which makes sense, as it waited for your `Task` to finish, all that's left is the result.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that! I totally get it now :)

Answer (score 3):

Because async methods don't return values. They return promise to return value when computation will be finished. Methods return immediately before computation finishes, before actual string is produced.

Comment: So you are saying that the method GetWeatherAsync() returns immediately after the await serverResponse... is called? It is weir dbecause MSDN says: "The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx

Comment: @FunkyPeanut you can call it without await

Comment: @FunkyPeanut You can consider your line of code to be equivalent to: `Task<string> tmp = GetWeatherAsync(); Console.WriteLine(await tmp);`, so the call to `GetWeatherAsync` is done before the `Console.WriteLine()`, then the `Console.WriteLine` has to wait for the result of the call (`await`)

Comment: AH! I could swear I got an error before when I tried it without await... Now I get it... And when I want to return only a Task I have to remove the "async" Keyword from the function, right?

Comment: @FunkyPeanut If your method contains the `await` keyword then it must contain the `async` modifier. The `async` modifier marks the method as a method that must be modified during compilation time (it is transformed in a state machine)

Comment: Yeah, try looking at the generated IL for async methods!

Comment: @DavidG But take a pill for migraine before doing it :-)